# SVN::Client commit with comment/message option

Tags: perl, svn

I am trying to automate some svn tasks with perl **SVN::Client** module.

Unfortunately I couldn't find an option to commit a file with commit message.
Currenty I am using following method.

```
$client->commit($targets, $nonrecursive, $pool);
```

Does anyone know how can I add comment/message in svn commit with SVN::Client?
Is there any alternative options with perl to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation of SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm) says you need to use the `log_msg` callback.

> $client->commit($targets, $nonrecursive, $pool);
>
> Commit files or directories referenced by target. Will use the log_msg callback to obtain the log message for the commit.

Here's what the doc says about `log_msg`.

> $client->log_msg(\&log_msg)
>
> Sets the log_msg callback for the client
>   context to a code reference that you pass. It always returns the
>   current codereference set.
>
> The subroutine pointed to by this coderef will be called to get the
>   log message for any operation that will commit a revision to the repo.
>
> It receives 4 parameters. The first parameter is a reference to a
>   scalar value in which the callback should place the log_msg. If you
>   wish to cancel the commit you can set this scalar to undef. The 2nd
>   value is a path to any temporary file which might be holding that log
>   message, or undef if no such file exists (though, if log_msg is undef,
>   this value is undefined). The log message MUST be a UTF8 string with
>   LF line separators. The 3rd parameter is a reference to an array of
>   svn_client_commit_item3_t objects, which may be fully or only
>   partially filled-in, depending on the type of commit operation. The
>   4th and last parameter will be a pool.
>
> If the function wishes to return an error it should return a
>   svn_error_t object made with SVN::Error::create. Any other return
>   value will be interpreted as SVN_NO_ERROR.

According to this, probably the easiest way is to just call that every time you want to make a commit, and install a new message.

```
$client->log_msg( sub { 
    my ( $msg_ref, $path, $array_of_commit_obj, $pool ) = @_;

    # set the message, beware the scalar reference
    $$msg_ref = "Initial commit\n\nFollowed by a wall of text...";

    return; # undef should be treated like SVN_NO_ERROR
});

$client->commit($targets, $nonrecursive, $pool);

# possibly call log_msg again to reset it.
```

If you want this to be easier, you can install that same handler once, but use a (possibly global or package) variable for the message.

```
our $commit_message;
$client->log_msg( sub { 
    my ( $msg_ref, $path, $array_of_commit_obj, $pool ) = @_;

    # set the message, beware the scalar reference
    $$msg_ref = $commit_message;

    return; # undef should be treated like SVN_NO_ERROR
});

# ...

for my $targets ( @list_of_targets ) {
    $commit_message = get_msg($targets); # or whatever
    $client->commit($targets, $nonrecursive, $pool);
}
```

This way you are reusing the callback, but changing the message every time.

---

Please note that I have not tried this. All I've done is read the documentation and making some wild guesses.